# React Hooks accessing state from useState before it's declared

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to learn how React hooks work with a simple authentication modal that I've set up. I have a custom `useForm` hook that handles form state, and I'm curious as to how I have access to `values` before it's declared.

```
function LoginModal () {
   console.log('outside values', values) // undefined
   const submitForm = async () => {
     console.log('inside values', values) // email, password values exist
     const request = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/auth/login',
        data: {
           email: values.email,
           password: values.password
        }
    }
    await axios(request)
  }

  const [values, handleChange, handleSubmit] = useForm(submitForm)

  return <div>some form stuff</div>
}

`useForm.js`

import { useState } from 'react'

const useForm = submitForm => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({})

  const handleChange = event => {
    event.persist()
    setState(state => ({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }))
  }

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    submitForm()
  }

  return [state, handleChange, handleSubmit]
}

export default useForm
```

Can someone explain to me why `values` exist only within the `submitForm` function, and how it's available before `const [values]` is even declared? I believe `const` declarations aren't hoisted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a function JS will keep that function declaration in memory and will give access the its respective local and global scope. This is what happens to your `submitForm` function. In the example from the snippet below, this is the `someFunc` function.

As you can see form the example below, if you execute that function **before** the variable `values` has been declared, you'll get `undefined`. Because it's not in scope yet.

But if you execute the function through a click event like you're doing, **after** the variable `values` has been defined, your function will be able to 'see' the variable because it's already in scope.

**NOTE:** You're correct. `const` declarations are not hoisted.

```js
function App() {
  
  // WHEN YOU CALL IT THROUGH A CLICK EVENT, THE VARIABLE `values` WILL BE IN SCOPE
  function someFunc() {
    console.log('State from someFunc(): ' + values);
  }
  
  console.log('State from component body BEFORE variable "values" declaration: ' + values);
  
  someFunc(); // WHEN EXECUTED AT THIS POINT. IT HAS NO ACCESS TO 'values' BECAUSE IT'S STILL undefined
  
  const [values,setValues] = React.useState(['a','b','c']);
  
  console.log('State from component body AFTER variable "values" declaration: ' + values);
  
  return(
    <button onClick={someFunc}>Click to run someFunc()</button>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```